# SSAS Tabular Model converts numerical values to text in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas

I am a newbie and I am trying to analyse `SSAS` tabular model data in `Excel`. But each time click the analyse in Excel button the data gets loaded into `Excel` ***but converts all numerical values into text and becomes impossible to create a pivot table***.  Is there any way around this?
I want my numerical values to remain numerical and not converted to text 
I have tried using text to columns 
I have tried multiplying the values by 1
I have tried so many other options but none of them worked
All suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Comment: Can you not deploy your solution, and then connect to the tabular modular from excel. Data > From Other Sources > Analysis Server. 
If you don't want to deploy, you can connect to your workspace server.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will try this and let you know how it goes.  Many Thanks